# Flutter - ErrorWidget.builder Cant Catch Error

Tags: flutter

Currently, an overflow error is occurring on my screen.

I want to show the custom widget to the user when a flutter error occurs like an overflow error.

Therefore, I used ErrorWidget.builder to show Container() when a flutter error occurs.

However, the ErrorWidget.builder function is not being invoked when an error occurs.

So the screen shows a dirty overflow error.

Is it a bug in the flutter? Or is the setting wrong?

On the other hand, FlutterError.onError is normally used to catch overflow errors. Like this:

```
FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) => print('It's work!');
```

However, FlutterError.onError cannot return a widget.

I need to use ErrorWidget.builder to return a custom widget if a flutter error occurs.

Here is my code :

**main function**

```
void main() {
  ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) => Container();
  runApp(app());
}
```

**app function**

```
Widget app() {
  return GetMaterialApp(
    initialRoute: AppRoutes.HOME, // overflow error occurrence point
    getPages: AppPages.pages,
  );
}
```

**overflow error log**

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 6.0 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column Column:file:///lib/app/ui/common/widget/game_card.dart:18:14
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.
```

- Additional

https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/errors

I put ErrorWidget.builder inside the MaterialApp builder like the "Define a custom error widget for build phase errors" section of the document and it still doesn't work.

My Flutter version

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.5 <3.0.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As is described in the API documentation for `ErrorWidget` [This widget is used when a build method fails](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ErrorWidget-class.html) but an overflow error happens [during the rendering phase](https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/architectural-overview#from-user-input-to-the-gpu), after the widget tree was built.
2. The overflow error will only be visible during debug mode. And it is not actually an exception which is thrown. It is [only reported to the console](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/efd006e1b925f50a66d5941b4f811966694baab0/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/debug_overflow_indicator.dart#L239-L257). Although `reportError` will use the `FlutterError.onError` you mentioned. If you really like to you could probably store a global reference to some widget state, where you display an error message.